# WP Rest API V2 CORS error preflight response

Tags: php, angularjs, wordpress, rest

I'm trying to develop a web app with AngularJS that's managed with WordPress. I've installed WP and the WP Rest API V2 plugin. I want to get my response with Angular's $http and work with the returned data.

I have my factory that looks like this:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    /**
     * @ngdoc function
     * @name app.service:prayersService
     * @description
     * # prayersService
     * Service of the app
     */

    angular
        .module('prayers')
        .factory('PrayersService', Prayers);
        // Inject your dependencies as .$inject = ['$http', 'someSevide'];
        // function Name ($http, someSevide) {...}

        Prayers.$inject = ['$q', '$http'];

        function Prayers ($q, $http) {

            return{
                get: function(){
                    return $http.get('https://drummerboyhosting.com/sandbox/rosary/wp-json/wp/v2/rosary_prayers/')
                }
            }

        }

})();
```

So when I visit my site and try to log the results on my localhost I get this error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://drummerboyhosting.com/sandbox/rosary/wp-json/wp/v2/rosary_prayers/. Request header field X-Requested-With is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend you to Allow all cross-origin requests to your WordPress site's REST API. I wrote a [plugin](https://github.com/ahmadawais/WP-REST-Allow-All-CORS) for just that.

Answer (score 0):

according to "Ahmad Awais":

```
// Hook.
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'wp_rest_allow_all_cors', 15 );

/**
 * Allow all CORS.
 *
 * @since 1.0.0
 */
function wp_rest_allow_all_cors() {
    // Remove the default filter.
    remove_filter( 'rest_pre_serve_request', 'rest_send_cors_headers' );

    // Add a Custom filter.
    add_filter( 'rest_pre_serve_request', function( $value ) {
        header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *' );
        header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE' );
        header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true' );
        header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *' );
        return $value;
    });
}
```